# What are the attributes of dash.Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am new to dash, but so far it was quite intuitive to build simple interactive graphs and other apps with it. However, now I want to dive a bit more into it. I used one of the example dashboards they provide on Plotly website. Nowhere I can find any documentation regarding the attributes of `dash.Dash`.

For example:

```
app = dash.Dash(
        __name__,
        meta_tags=[{"name":"viewport", "content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],
    )
```

Where can I find all possible attributes of the dash.Dash? And what is `meta_tags`?

I will be thankful to any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place is probably going to be inside Dash itself, which you can view in your files, or on Github. [Here is the section](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/dev/dash/dash.py#L191-L194) about `meta_tags`.

Keep in mind that Dash is actually a Flask server. It will inherit properties from Flask, which are much better explained on [their docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at the Flask docs.